# Call REST services from Chef Recipes and save the output from API called for the further process

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to use Chef recipes to call the ready available REST APIs for my product. So that using chef it will be a complete automation for installation of various components and settings. In short need a way to call REST services and save the output to somewhere.

Not lot of examples are available on net for this. As I am new can anyone throw some light as how to achieve this or some where to look into.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Give a look at the [http_request](https://docs.chef.io/resource_http_request.html) resource. And FWIW the whole https://docs.chef.io

Comment: Also consider writing an Ohai plugin. Gets called early in the chef run, very useful for saving information as part of the node object. Simple for chef resources to later access. See: https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html

Answer (score 1):

Very late to answer but I hope it will help someone else.
A simple example would be to call an api with GET method.

**recipe/default.rb**

```
template '/etc/response.txt' do
        owner "root"
        group "root"
        mode "0644"
        source "response.erb"
        variables({
                response:Chef::HTTP.new('https://www.metaweather.com/').get('/api/location/44418/',{'Accept'=> 'application/json', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json'})
        })
end
```

**templates/response.erb**

```
<%= @response %>
```

This will produce the json response at /etc/response.txt.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't documented very well, but you can use Chef's HTTP client class for this. Check out https://coderanger.net/chef-tips/#4 for an example of basic usage.

Comment: Is this considered a public API though? I've seen a lot of heartache over folks that used `rest_client` when it was shipped in Chef 11.x and then wasn't included in Chef 12.

Comment: It's "mostly public". There are docstring comments in place and it wouldn't change unless there was a compelling reason, and I would push for that to be a major version breakage like `rest_client`'s removal was.

Comment: (remember public APIs can change without compat between major versions)